# epsilon-delta proof for lim x/(1+\sin^2(x))

Tags: calculus

> Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$, where $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{1+\sin^2{x}}$.

**Attempt**

We need to show that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad 0 < |x-a| < \delta \quad \implies \quad \left | \dfrac{x}{1+\sin^2{x}}-\left ( \dfrac{a}{1+\sin^2{a}} \right) \right| < \epsilon.$$

The problem here is that I can't really factor out $|x-a|$ easily from that so I am lost how to proceed next. We can substitute in $a = 0$ to get $\left| \dfrac{x}{1+\sin^2{x}} \right| < \epsilon$ but then how do we relate delta?

Comment: Notice that $1+\sin^2(x)≥1$, so $1/(1+\sin^2(x))≤1$ for all $x$. If $|x|<\delta$ how can you combine these two things and choose $\delta$ to get a helpful expression? Aside from that, $\epsilon-\delta$ usually refers to the definition of _continuity_ and not to the evaluation of a limit. I believe your exercise does not want you to evaluate a limit but rather show continuity of a function at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $1+\sin^2 x \geq 1$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{x}{1 + \sin^2 x}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x}{1}\right| = |x|
$$
Clearly, if $|x|<\epsilon$, then $\left|\frac{x}{1 + \sin^2 x}\right| < \epsilon$. Therefore, it suffices to pick $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: What if $|x| \not < \epsilon$?

Comment: @user19405892 But it is, if you choose $\delta = \epsilon$. We are, after all, only interested in $|x|<\delta$.